# A button that calls a function in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I'd like to add a button to my APEX application that asks me for a variable's value and runs an Oracle function with that variable.

Is it possible?

Comment: Absolutely, but... Define "asks me for a variable" - what is the flow you are expecting: a user clicks the button and then what ?  a popup screen ? a new page item that appears ? Then once that function is executed, do you expect anything to be done with the return value ? It would help if you explained the flow in as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, a simpler option is to create an **item** (that's "ask for a variable's value") and a **button** which - when pressed - runs a **process** which calls the function, passes item's value to it and returns the result *somewhere* (another page item, for example):

```
:P1_RESULT := f_my_function (:P1_TEXT_ITEM);
```

Comment: And vitally, set the page items to submit & return in the PL/SQL dynamic action